# Find a non-trivial function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $N$ be a finite non-negative integer value random variable
Let $Q_k=P(N\geq k)$

My question is : **is there a function $f(X)$ which is not 0 or 1 functions such that**

$$\frac{1}{Q_k}\sum_{i=k}^{\infty} f^2(i)P(N=i) \equiv\text{ a finite fixed constant}, \forall k\geq 0$$ ?

I think there must be exists such a function since the above sum is "considered" as the average of $f^2(x)$ on $\{ i: i\geq k\}$.   Here $N$ can take to be a shifted Geometric R.V.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c$ be the finite fixed constant. Note that $Q_k = P(N \ge k) = \displaystyle\sum_{i = k}^{\infty}P(N = i)$.

So, by multiplying both sides of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{Q_k}\sum_{i=k}^{\infty} f^2(i)P(N=i) = c$ by $Q_k$, we get $\displaystyle\sum_{i=k}^{\infty} f^2(i)P(N=i) = \sum_{i = k}^{\infty}cP(N = i)$ for all $k \ge 0$.

Since this holds for all $k \ge 0$, it holds when $k$ is replaced by $k+1$, i.e. $\displaystyle\sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty} f^2(i)P(N=i) = \sum_{i = k+1}^{\infty}cP(N = i)$ for all $k \ge -1$.

Subtracting these two equations gives us $f^2(k)P(N = k) = cP(N = k)$ for all $k \ge 0$.

Thus, for each integer $k \ge 0$, we must have either $f^2(k) = c$ or $P(N = k) = 0$.

If $N$ is a random variable such that $P(N = k) > 0$ for all integers $k \ge 0$, then $f^2(k)$ must be constant.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy ! It is a very nice solution !